# React-router does not render

Tags: reactjs, react-router, router

I am trying to set up react-router but for some reason it is not rendering anything

```
import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Routes } from 'react-router-dom';
import Header from './components/Header';
import Home from './pages/Home';
import Segment from './pages/Segment';
import List from './pages/List';
import Chat from './pages/Chat';

function App() {

  console.log(window.location.pathname==="/segment");
  console.log(window.location.pathname)
  return (
    <>
    <Router>
      <Header />
      <Routes>
        <Route exact path="/segment" component={<Segment/>} />
        <Route path="/" component={Home} />
      </Routes>
    </Router>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

When I navigate to "/segment", browser does not render anything, I checked everywhere but can not get my head around, `"react-router-dom": "^6.3.0",`

My Segment component is

```
import React from "react";

const Segment = () => {
  console.log('renedr');
  return (
    <div>
      test
    </div>
  );
}

export default Segment;
```

Comment: Does your home component render when you navigate to / ?

Comment: Looks like you're using old router syntax with new router (6.x). New syntax uses `element`, and not `component` prop.

Comment: right to the point, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I use `"react-router-dom": "^6.3.0"` `<Outlet />` and i use lazy load render component.

```
import "./App.css";
import {
  BrowserRouter,
  Route,
  Router,
  Routes,
  useNavigate,
} from "react-router-dom";
import Layout from "./components/shared/Layout";

const Home = React.lazy(() => './pages/Home');
const Segment = React.lazy(() => './pages/Segment');
const List = React.lazy(() => './pages/List');
const Chat = React.lazy(() => './pages/Chat');

function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <Container fluid="true">
        <BrowserRouter>
          <Routes>
            <Route
              path="/"
              element={<Layout />}
            >
              <Route
                path="/"
                element={
                  <React.Suspense fallback={<>...</>}>
                    <Home />
                  </React.Suspense>
                }
              />
              <Route
                path="/segment"
                element={
                  <React.Suspense fallback={<>...</>}>
                    <Segment />
                  </React.Suspense>
                }
              />
              <Route
                path="/list"
                element={
                  <React.Suspense fallback={<>...</>}>
                    <List />
                  </React.Suspense>
                }
              />
              <Route
                path="/chat"
                element={
                  <React.Suspense fallback={<>...</>}>
                    <Chat />
                  </React.Suspense>
                }
              />
              <Route
                path="*"
                element={
                  <React.Suspense fallback={<>...</>}>
                    <NotFound />
                  </React.Suspense>
                }
              />
            </Route>
          </Routes>
        </BrowserRouter>
      </Container>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import { Container } from "react-bootstrap";
import { Outlet } from "react-router-dom";
import Footer from "./Footer";
import Header from "./Header";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";

const Layout = () => {

  return (
    <>
      <Header></Header>
        <Container className="content">
          <Outlet />
        </Container>
      <Footer></Footer>
    </>
  );
};

export default Layout;
```

Comment: Appreciate you going through the effort of fixing the actual code. However, please add some kind of description to explain what you have done that would help the topic starter (and other readers) understand what you're getting at.

Answer (score 0):

## Issue

The `Route` component API changed significantly in `react-router-dom@6`. There  are no longer a `component`, or `render` and `children` function props, all replaced by a single `element` prop taking a `ReactNode`, a.k.a. JSX.

## Solution

Render all the routed content on the `element` prop as JSX. There is also no `exact` prop, all routes are now *always* exactly matched.

Example:

```
<Router>
  <Header />
  <Routes>
    <Route path="/segment" element={<Segment/>} />
    <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
  </Routes>
</Router>
```

You may want to review the [Upgrade from v5](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/upgrading/v5) guide for other breaking changes from v5 to v6.